# Sum of product of Stirling numbers

Tags: summation, factorial, stirling-numbers

We have for $n>0$, $k>0$
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\min(n,k)}(j!)^2{n\brace j}{k+1\brace j+1}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\min(n,k-1)}j!(j+1)!{n+1\brace j+1}{k\brace j+1}$$
How can we prove it?

Comment: Do you have any context?

Comment: For the second sum "Masanobu Kaneko. Multiple zeta values, poly-Bernoulli numbers, and related zeta functions. Nagoya Math Journal, 153:189-201, 1999". First one is mine and based on previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the recurrence relation for the Stirling numbers of the second kind
\begin{eqnarray*}
{k+1\brace j+1}=(j+1){k\brace j+1}+{k\brace j}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The sum becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
S&=&\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\min(n,k)}(j!)^2{n\brace j}{k+1\brace j+1} \\ &=& \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\min(n,k)}(j!)((j+1)!){n\brace j}{k\brace j+1} +\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\min(n,k)}(j!)^2{n\brace j}{k\brace j}
\end{eqnarray*}
 shift the second summation variable by $1$
\begin{eqnarray*}
S&=& \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\min(n,k-1)}(j!)((j+1)!){k\brace j+1} \left({n\brace j}+(j+1){n\brace j+1}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the recurrence formula again 
\begin{eqnarray*}
{n+1\brace j+1}={n\brace j}+(j+1){n\brace j+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
& we are done.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much!